# Adding to an array in MongoDB using $addToSet

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I'm trying to add data to an array defined in my mongoDB called "signedUp" it is within my Timetable Schema. So far i've been able to update other fields of my schema correctly however my signedUp array always remains empty. I ensured the variable being added was not empty.

Here is my Schema

```
var TimetableSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

date: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  spaces: {
    type: Number,        
    required: true
  },
  classes: [ClassSchema],
  signedUp: [{
    type: String
  }]


});
```

This was my latest attempt but no value is ever added to the signedUp array.
My API update request

```
id = {_id: req.params.id};
space = {spaces: newRemainingCapacity};
signedUp = {$addToSet:{signedUp: currentUser}};
Timetable.update(id,space,signedUp,function(err, timetable){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("updates");
    res.send({timetable});
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Both `space` and `signedUp` should be passed as a second parameter. Are you trying to update `spaces` or replace entire document ?

Comment: @mickl  At the moment i have a spaces counter which updates and i want the array signedup to update, so does that mean i need to split them up into two updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at [db.collection.update()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update) documentation. Second parameter takes `update` and 3rd one represents operation options while you're trying to pass your `$addToSet` as third param. Your operation should look like below:

```
id = {_id: req.params.id};
space = { $set: { spaces: newRemainingCapacity }};
signedUp = { $addToSet:{ signedUp: currentUser}};
update = { ...space, ...signedUp }

Timetable.update(id,update,function(err, timetable){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("updates");
    res.send({timetable});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

space and signedUp are together the second argument. 
try this:

```
id = {_id: req.params.id};
space = {spaces: newRemainingCapacity};
signedUp = {$addToSet:{signedUp: currentUser}};
Timetable.update(id, {...space, ...signedUp}, function(err, timetable){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("updates");
    res.send({timetable});
});
```

Comment: Try to console.log `{space, signedUp}`